# How would you like to Share on LinkedIn using PHP OAuth Class

Tags: php

I'm trying to use the CallAPI function to post a status remotely after I get the tokens, but it's not working for some reason.
Here is my code:

```
if (($success = $client->Initialize())) {
    if (($success = $client->Process())) {
        if (strlen($client->access_token)) {
            $url = 'http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares';
            $method = 'POST';
            $parameters = array('comment' => 'Some comment', 'content' => 'Some content', 'title' => 'Some title');
            $options = array();
            $success = $client->CallAPI($url, $method, $parameters, $options, $response);
        }
    }

    $success = $client->Finalize($success);
}
```

I'm doing something wrong, but I can't find out what, because it doesn't give me any errors.

Comment: Be careful about using multiple `$success` variables, could get a little messy. Where abouts does it stop working? Do you get any errors? [This might help you writing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: no errors, but i am not getting any post on linkedin wall after execution of code

Comment: What are thw values returned into those `$success` variables? Also - where is `$response` set?

Comment: if (($success = $client->Initialize())) {
    if (($success = $client->Process())) {
        if (strlen($client->access_token)) {
           $success = $client->CallAPI(
   'http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,email-address,first-name,last-name,location,picture-url,public-profile-url,formatted-name)', 
   'GET', array(
    'format'=>'json'
   ), array('FailOnAccessError'=>true), $user);
        }
    }

    $success = $client->Finalize($success);
}

Comment: above code also working fine whenever we are getting profile details, but CallAPI not working for saharing on wall of linkedin